# Ex 0.2.1 in Sachs and Wu's textbook

Tags: general-relativity

In the next attachements are:
1. Exercise 0.2.5 which I want help with.

2. Proposition 0.2.1 and its proof.

Now, basically a few things are changed in the theorem, I don't think I can use here the definition of s(t) in the proof of prop0.2.1 cause its s(t)=0, I don't think I can use this trick here.

Other thoughts that I had, obviously if I plug m=0 into prop0.2.1 I get that I should have:
$$\frac{d\gamma^1}{du}=\pm \frac{d\gamma^2}{du}$$, and $$\frac{d\gamma^2}{du}=a$$.

My question is how do I satisfy condition b in the theorem, I guess this x should be $$\pm Id +constant$$

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Can you please give us a full reference for the book?  Mainly title, edition, authors.

Comment: OK. Sachs and Wu, GR for Mathematicians, 1977 edition.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an attempt at this exercise: Is the following alright?:

If we take $\mathcal{E}=\mathbb{R}$, and $\gamma:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\gamma u=(x(au),au)$, for $u\in \mathcal{E}=\mathbb{R}$, then $\gamma_∗ u=a\frac{dx}{du}(au)\partial_{u^1}+a\partial_{u^2}$. This gives:

(a) $du^2(\gamma_∗u)=(a\frac{dx}{du}(au)\partial_{u^1}+a\partial_{u^2})(u^2)=0+a⋅1=a$,

(b) $\gamma^1(u)=x(au)=x(\gamma^2 u)=(x\circ \gamma^2)(u)$ for all real $u$, and

(c) $g(\gamma_∗u,\gamma_∗u)=(a\frac{dx}{du}(au))^2−(a)^2=a^2[(\frac{dx}{du}(au))^2−1^2]=a^2⋅0=0$. Here we have used $v=|\frac{dx}{du}|=1$ everywhere.

I haven't yet tried showing uniqueness of $\mathcal{E}$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: It's nice that someone is trying to help me even after approximately 7 years, but I don't remember a lot from the book, so I cannot know for sure if your asnwer is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.